# How to remove text when pasting

Tags: applescript

I often copy and paste from iBook for personal note taking. How do I create a script that will automatically remove the words "Excerpt From" and all the words following that text whenever I paste in any application?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to run the script before you paste, and it might look something like this:

```
try
    set c to the clipboard as text
    considering case --to match exactly
        set o to offset of "Excerpt From" in c
    end considering
    set the clipboard to (text beginning thru (o - 1) of c)
on error e
    display dialog e
end try
```

--given text on clipboard like `"1234------Excerpt From 0987654"` you'd end up with `"1234------"`